# How to retrieve top 10 entries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table which looks like this - 
[image: Description]

I now want to retrieve top 10 `athleteName` based on the `time`. I know I can use `top` clause, but that returns the entries based on the top 10 ids. How can I retrieve the entries based on the `time`. I want to get the athletes with top 10 record times.

What is the correct SQL statement for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select atheletename from table order by time limit 0,10
```

Comment: what does 0, 10 do? Becuase other people only have 10, what is the function of 0?

Comment: here its doing nothing the 0 just to start from 0 but without writing 0 its also start from 0

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from scores order by time desc limit 0,10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from yourtable
order by time desc
limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select max(`time`) ,atheletename from table order by atheletename limit 10 DESC
```